# Cannot download file in headless chrome

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to download a file using headless chrome.

In normale mode, it works without problem, 
but in headeless, no matter what prefs or options I set, it doesn't download the pdf without any exception or error.

```
 ChromeDriverService service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
            service.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;

            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

            options.AddArgument("--ignore-certificate-errors");
            options.AddArgument("--disable-popup-blocking");
            options.AddArgument("--disable-infobars");
            options.AddArgument("--disable-extensions");
            options.AddArgument("--disable-default-apps");
            options.AddArgument("--disable-gpu");
            options.AddArgument("--window-size=1920,1080");
            options.AddArgument("--user-agent=Chrome/73.0.3683.103");
            options.AddArgument("--headless");
            options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory",downloadsPath); 

options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.prompt_for_download",false);            
options.AddUserProfilePreference("safebrowsing.disable_download_protection",true);            options.AddUserProfilePreference("plugins.always_open_pdf_externally", true);

            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(service, options);
            driver.Manage().Cookies.DeleteAllCookies();
            var enableDownloadCommandParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                { "behavior", "allow" },
                { "downloadPath", downloadsPath }
            };
            object  rt = ((ChromeDriver)driver).ExecuteChromeCommandWithResult("Page.setDownloadBehavior", enableDownloadCommandParameters);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is bug in headless mode which was reported on 27 February 2017.

***What is the expected result?***

When launching in headless mode and pointing to an URL with a downloadable file, file should be downloaded and saved in "Downloads" folder.

***What happens instead?***

Nothing happens, file doesn't get downloaded.

Bug link - https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=696481

Comment: I see, thank you for the information. They suggest using Page.setDownloadBehavior, But I've already tried it. I'll search for some workaround.